# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'settingsText' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and coding in general, and I'm trying to write a program that allows you to draw using turtle graphics, here is my code:

```
import turtle

# Setup
bot = turtle.Turtle()
bot.speed(5)
bot.color("black")
x = 1
color = "black"
speed = 5
length = 20
visibility = "true"
inputText = '''Choose an option:
A) Forward
B) Backward
C) Left
D) Right
E) Settings
F) Exit
> '''

settingsText = "Choose a setting: \nA) Color: " + str(color) + "\nB) Speed: " + str(speed) + "\nC) Length: " + str(length) + "\nD) Visibility: " + str(visibility) + "\n> "

def main():
    while x == 1:
        mainMenu = input(inputText)
        if mainMenu == "A":
            bot.forward(length)
        elif mainMenu == "B":
            bot.backward(length)
        elif mainMenu == "C":
            bot.left(90)
        elif mainMenu == "D":
            bot.right(90)
        elif mainMenu == "E":
            while x == 1:
                settingsMenu = input(settingsText)
                global settingsText
                if settingsMenu == "A":
                    color = input("What color should the bot write with?")
                    bot.color(color)
                if settingsMenu == "B":
                    speed = input("How fast should the bot move?")
                    bot.speed(speed)
                if settingsMenu == "C":
                    length = input("How far should the bot move each time?")
                if settingsMenu == "D":
                    visibility = input("Should the bot be visible?")
                    if visibility == "true":
                        bot.showturtle()
                    if visibility == "false":
                        bot.hideturtle()
                if settingsMenu == "E":
                    break
                settingsText = "Choose a setting: \nA) Color: " + str(color) + "\nB) Speed: " + str(speed) + "\nC) Length: " + str(length) + "\nD) Visibility: " + str(visibility)
        elif mainMenu == "F":
            break


main()
```

When I currently run it, it says UnboundLocalError: local variable 'settingsText' referenced before assignment. How do I fix this? I read other posts that stated that you can't assign a variable inside the local scope (Whats a scope??) if its already been assigned elsewhere or something. That makes no sense though, I'm assigning the variable at the start, then just giving it a new assignment at the end of an if loop so that the next time the loop is played it says something different. Any help would be appreciated!

-Hero

Comment: Mention the statement `global settingsText` before the statement `settingsMenu = input(settingsText)`. That way, the interpreter knows it has to use the one in global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `global` before you use the variable :

```
global settingsText
settingsMenu = input(settingsText)
```

also you'll have the same problem with variables like `length`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the line:

```
settingsMenu = input(settingsText)
```

You are declaring global settingsText after using it. It will not work.You should declare global variables before using them or else it'll be taken as a local variable.

Try making all variables that you want as global at the top of the function. This way you will see all of them together.

Also, try not to use global variables at all. It is considered as bad practice and in most cases have simple workarounds.